# Flutter Ble Advertisement

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to broadcast custom ble advertisement data from an ios/android device to many custom BLE Devices. My goal is to set the bytes of the ble adv package to broadcast it to ble devices nearby.

As far as is i know i need to set the payload of the advertise package of my ios / android device.

In my case it isn’t possible to simply connect to every ble device and write characteristics values, because i need to broadcast data to many devices.

Is there any way to solve this problem with flutter / flutter blue?

Answer (score 1):

Advertisement is not meant to connect to devices, just advertising data.

If a device is advertising, it is up to the receiver to make a connection and exchange data.
 This is only possible if the application on the receiver is made for the advertising device, or has some pre-defined protocol to interact with advertising devices that have the same protocol.
 In the advertising packet there is a flag that states if the advertiser is connectable or not.

Comment: Please read his question again. He is not planning to connect, instead wants to broadcast, and is looking for a way to do that in Flutter.

Comment: Anyone got the answer?